# Ionic cordova android build fails on concourse ci by saying "Gradle build daemon got exited"

Tags: android, docker, ionic-framework, gradle, concourse

We are currenly migrating an Ionic android build setup from bamboo to concourse. The android build using ionic cordova is triggered as one of the commands in a larger concourse-ci job which does npm install first and then does ionic build command.

The actual ionic command that fails is :

```
ionic cordova build android --dev --debug --release --no-interactive --no- confirm --buildConfig --nofetch --minifyjs --minifycss --gradleArg=--no-daemon
```

---

As a prerequisite to ionic cordova, I have ensured that gradle is installed correctly in the base docker image by doing wget of the gradle distribution and setting the gradle home environment variable to point to the downloaded gradle binary. Following is the content of the dockerfile :

```
FROM runmymind/docker-android-sdk

# make /bin/sh symlink to bash instead of dash:
RUN echo "dash dash/sh boolean false" | debconf-set-selections \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg-reconfigure dash

# Installing NodeJS
RUN ARCH=x64 \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO --compressed "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 --no-same-owner \
 && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-$ARCH.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
 && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

# Installing gradle
ENV GRADLE_VERSION 3.3
RUN mkdir /opt/gradle \
 && wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip \
 && unzip -d /opt/gradle gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}-bin.zip
 ENV GRADLE_HOME /opt/gradle/gradle-${GRADLE_VERSION}/bin
 ENV PATH $PATH:$GRADLE_HOME
```

When using this docker image; the docker container comes up and I am able to access the gradle correctly. However when invoking the above ionic cordova build command after installing cordova7 we get a detailed error message :
**Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed or may have crashed**. The detailed error message is follows :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Gradle build daemon disappeared unexpectedly (it may have been killed
>   or may have crashed)
>   * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.      Error: /opt/gradle/gradle-3.3/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android --debug
>   --release 
>           --buildConfig (exit code 1).

*We tried using latest gradle build version 4.6 and the problem persist* and the gradle daemon gets killed immediately. Some of the gradle logs thats gets printed in the concourse ci :

> > cordova build android --debug --release --buildConfig
>
> You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova
>   telemetry on.      will push strings array
>   {"name":"lang","titles":["English (US)","English
>   (UK)"],"values":["en-us","en-gb"]}     android preferences file was
>   successfully generated     ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux
>   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64    Reading build config
>   file: /tmp/build/80754af9/source/build.json    Reading the keystore
>   from: /tmp/build/80754af9/source/Elsa2Go_android.keystore      Starting a
>   Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)   The message
>   received from the daemon indicates that the daemon has disappeared.
>   Build request sent: Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source}     Attempting to read last
>   messages from the daemon log...    Daemon pid: 731
>        log file: /root/.gradle/daemon/3.3/daemon-731.out.log
>   ----- Last  20 lines from daemon log file - daemon-731.out.log -----   10:01:27.698 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonStartupCommunication]
>   Completed writing the daemon greeting. Closing streams...
>   10:01:27.795 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon]
>   stopOnExpiration() called on daemon    10:01:27.799 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] awaitExpiration() called on
>   daemon     10:01:27.800 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpIncomingConnector]
>   Accepted connection from /127.0.0.1:54152 to /127.0.0.1:45644.
>   10:01:27.801 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is
>   running. Sleeping until state changes.     10:01:27.950 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection]
>   thread 14: received class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
>   10:01:27.950 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultDaemonConnection] thread 14:
>   Received non-IO message from client:
>   Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source}     10:01:27.951 [INFO]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler]
>   Received command: Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source}.    10:01:27.951 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler]
>   Starting executing command:
>   Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source} with connection: socket
>   connection from /127.0.0.1:45644 to /127.0.0.1:54152.      10:01:27.953
>   [ERROR] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator]
>   Command execution: started DaemonCommandExecution[command =
>   Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source}, connection =
>   DefaultDaemonConnection: socket connection from /127.0.0.1:45644 to
>   /127.0.0.1:54152] after 0.0 minutes of idle    10:01:27.954 [INFO]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonRegistryUpdater] Marking the
>   daemon as busy, address: [2f4d8bed-fcce-4001-8cd5-896af7ca9860
>   port:45644, addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]    10:01:27.954 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry] Marking
>   busy by address: [2f4d8bed-fcce-4001-8cd5-896af7ca9860 port:45644,
>   addresses:[/127.0.0.1]]    10:01:27.955 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire
>   exclusive lock on daemon addresses registry.   10:01:27.956 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired.
>   10:01:27.957 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on
>   daemon addresses registry.     10:01:27.957 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] resetting
>   idle timer     10:01:27.958 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator] daemon is
>   running. Sleeping until state changes.     10:01:27.961 [INFO]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy]
>   Daemon is about to start building
>   Build{id=a31854f5-a2c8-4248-b580-2ae398dbba4c.1,
>   currentDir=/tmp/build/80754af9/source}. Dispatching build started
>   information...     10:01:27.967 [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection]
>   thread 16: dispatching class
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted   10:01:27.996
>   [DEBUG]
>   [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment]
>   Configuring env variables: ............. ..................

P.S : Version information

- "ionic": "3.19.0"
- "@angular/cli": "1.5.3"
- Android plaftorm : installed in ionic

Approaches tried but same issue was observed :

- *Setting the gradle daemon as false in gradle properties by :*    **org.gradle.daemon=false**
- *Setting the heap size to a mininum in gradle properties by :*     **org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
  -Xms256m -Xmx512m**
- Using latest version of gradle 4.6

Any idea / suggestions as to what is the root cause will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What happens, if you remove the --no-daemon from the args? 
I mean Gradle says that the preferred way is the deamon since Gradle 3.0 (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon).
Furthermore you don't have a need for it, because Docker provides you a fresh environment.

Comment: Will try reverting the --no-daemon. Thanks.